# bounds.contains failed while it should not

Tags: google-maps-api-3

On the example http://gmap3.net/issues/contains-failed.html

map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition()) failed while the marker is visible,

if i change the map width from 1200px to 800px, it succeed

is it a known issue ?

Regards,

Jean-Baptiste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With '`800px`' width, you have these bounds:

```
(-57.31109738854086, -173.32397500000002),    //south west GPS -> sw
(84.67616358203445, 178.23852499999998)       //north east GPS -> ne
```

In '`1200px`' case:

```
(-57.31109738854086, 151.51977499999998),    //south west GPS  -> sw
(84.67616358203445, -146.60522500000002)     //north east GPS  -> ne
```

Your marker have `(49.00408, 2.562279999999987)` coordinates.So for 1st case:

```
-57.31109738854086    <    49.00408         <     84.67616358203445   //true
-173.32397500000002   <  2.562279999999987  <     178.23852499999998  //true
```

and for 2nd one:

```
-57.31109738854086    <    49.00408         <     84.67616358203445   //true
151.51977499999998    <  2.562279999999987  <    -146.60522500000002  //false
```

That is why, you get `"No"` as an alert in 2nd case, and `"Yes"` in 1st case.

Comment: But it seems to not be logical,

bounds should return true for all theses in the visible panel

oO

Comment: @jbdemonte I think, there is no easy way to check whether marker is visible on current view.The hack will be ,somehow retrieving marker's `DOM element`, then checking its position/offset and performing some maths.But you need to know, there could be multiple `DOM Element`s for the same marker.

Comment: i have to get it before it is append to the map, using latLng, so, i can't test the dom :/